# Why does my HAVING caluse return nothing?

Tags: mysql, sql

The problem is to find the Second Highest Salary from the employees table.
However my HAVING clause returns nothing, and I have no clue why. My logic is
I will just group by salary, and the condition I set in the HAVING clause is that
group by salary, only if salary != the maximum salary.

This way I thought I excluded the highest value for salary in the grouping, and
then I will only display the first record, which I thought would be the 2nd highest salary.

```
SELECT salary                  
FROM Employee
GROUP BY salary
HAVING salary != MAX(salary)
ORDER BY salary desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Every salary is equal to the max salary when grouping by salary.

Comment: When you group by salary, every salary is in its own group, and it's the max in that group.

Comment: Use a subquery to get the max salary of all, then compare with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the max salary:

```
SELECT salary               
FROM Employee
WHERE salary != (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee)
ORDER BY salary desc
LIMIT 1
```

Grouping is not required.

---

You can use a join too:

```
SELECT MAX(a.salary) 
FROM Employee a
JOIN Employee b ON b.salary > a.salary
```

This works because the highest salary doesn't have a row to join to and so is excluded from the result.

It trades brevity for efficiency, but unless you have millions of employees (unlikely), it will execute fast enough.

Comment: Column aliases are not allowed in the WHERE clause

Comment: The second query will not be executed and even if it would, it would not select the second highest maximum in case the maximum appears twice or more.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Thanks. I misread the question, and found a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need group by, order by or limit at all, you just can take the highest salary that is smaller than the maximum:

```
SELECT MAX(salary)
FROM employee
WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employee);
```

Grouping or ordering should be avoided whenever they are not required due to their high execution time. In case the table contains very many rows, they make the query slow.